# How can I change Google logo behaviour in Firefox with a userContent.css tweak?

Tags: firefox, google-search

Recently, Google changed the behavior of the Google logo on the subsearchpage (after you make a search and the logo is in the left corner) using Firefox 10 (<strike>probably since Firefox 8</strike> same since version 3.6).

As I figured it out, the logo doesn't act like a "button image" anymore (for ex. [this](http://support.google.com/bin/request.py?hl=en&ctx=go&contact_type=surveyk) still does).

I would like to change the behaviour of the logo, so I can use the right-click mouse button to open a new search homepage in a new tab. Maybe by using a userContent.css tweak?
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Google made this change on their site, so it is irrelevant to Firefox. Further more, `userContent.css` is for modifying CSS (styles). The functionality you are looking for is done with [user scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey). I agree that this was an unnecessary change, but in the meantime, you can click the `Search` link above the logo to do what you want.

[image: google]